# Can't get Snapcraft to create maven project

Tags: maven, ubuntu, javafx, yaml, snapcraft

I'm pretty new to snapcraft, and would like to publish an app on the Snap store. I created an application using javafx and compiled with maven. I have an executable jar that I would like to run. However, I cannot seem to configure my yaml file in a way that doesn't produce an error.

I have tried as many variations as I can think of with no avail.

system details:

```
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Snapcraft 7.5.4
java 21.0.1 2023-10-17 LTS
```

This is the most recent version of my yaml file:

```
name: green-collectives
base: core22
version: '1.0'
summary: Green Collectives - JavaFX Application
description: |
  A Desktop Application built with javaFx with the intention of solving relevant problems and inefficiencies that U.S. Army Service members, and gun enthusiasts face on a daily basis.

grade: stable
confinement: devmode

apps:
  green-collectives:
    command: java -jar $SNAP/target/greenSociety-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
    environment:
      JAVA_HOME: "$SNAP/home/tyty/.sdkman/candidates/java/21.0.1-oracle/bin"

parts:
  green-collectives:
    plugin: nil
    stage-packages:
      - default-jre
```

This particular yaml produces the error:

```
Command '['snap', 'pack', '--filename', 'green-collectives_1.0_amd64.snap', '--compression', 'xz', PosixPath('/root/prime'), PosixPath('/root/project')]' returned non-zero exit status 1.                                                     
Failed to execute pack in instance.                                            
Recommended resolution: Run the same command again with --debug to shell into the environment if you wish to introspect this failure.
```

I have also tried running as a maven project with the following yaml change:

```
parts:
  green-collectives:
    plugin: maven
    source: https://github.com/tcdickson/Green-Collectives.git
    source-type: git
    source-tag: master
```

with an error of:

```
Environment validation failed for part 'green-collectives': 'mvn' not found and part 'green-collectives' does not depend on a part named 'maven-deps' that would satisfy the dependency.
```

I have maven installed, and the project is compiled and packaged with maven

Comment: I [edited the question to format it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77572800/revisions) (it is just indenting relevant bits 4 spaces to treat them as preformatted blocks or code blocks).  Correctly formatting the content makes it more easily readable.

Comment: The error message says: "Recommended resolution: Run the same command again with --debug to shell into the environment if you wish to introspect this failure."  I suggest you do that.